# Is there any Safari extension similar to "WasteNoTime" that allows you to attribute different amounts of time for using different sites?

Tags: safari, software-recommendation, internet

Is there any Safari extension similar to "WasteNoTime" that allows you to attribute different amounts of time for using different sites?

For instance, let's say one wants to block completely Facebook full day but allow himself 30min of YouTube, 2h of Netflix and full access to Financial Times out of working hours (8h to 17h).

I couldn't find such features in the extensions like WasteNoTime.

Coud someone give me a help with that please?